# How to stop zooming out in Flot bar chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using Flot to draw some bar charts. How do I configure the zoom so that when a user zooms out, the chart will look like the one at the top and not like the one at the bottom? In other words, I don't want the user to continue zooming out when all of the data for the chart is shown. I also want to restrict the chart from displaying anything below 0 on the X axis. See my code and pictures of the charts below:

```
<#macro barChart2 var formatFunction ticks="" optionLegend="{ show: false }">
  var options = {
    yaxis: {
      tickFormatter: ${formatFunction}
    },
    series: {
      stack: 0,
      bars: { 
        show: true,
        barWidth: 0.9,
        align: "center"
      }
    },
    grid : { 
      hoverable: true 
    },
    xaxis: {
      <#if "${ticks}" != "">
        ticks: ${ticks}
      </#if>
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%b %d, %H:%M %P"
    },
    pan : { 
      interactive: true 
    },
    legend: ${optionLegend}
  };

  var plot${var} = $.plot($("#chart${var}"), data, options);

  $("#zoomIn${var}").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    plot${var}.zoom();
  });

  $("#zoomOut${var}").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    plot${var}.zoomOut();
  });
</#macro>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [`zoomRange` and `panRange` parameters](http://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.navigate.js?r=186)  that you can set with the navigation plugin. You specify those for the axes like:

```
xaxis: { zoomRange: [0.1, 10], panRange: [-10, 10] },
yaxis: { zoomRange: [0.1, 10], panRange: [-10, 10] }
```

where `zoomRange` sets the limit for zooming. In this case, the difference between the min and max will never go below 0.1, and it will never exceed 10. `panRange` tells the content to stay in a certain range, so in this case, neither axis will pan below -10 or above 10.

I'm not sure how you do this with time series data, but try with javascript timestamps to begin with.